# Decoding Signals from an Unknown Port on Spectrometer

Tags: fpga, signal, fft, port, pci

We have a Thermo-Nicolet Nexus 670 FT-IR Spectrophotometer, made in the USA around 2000. It was the work horse of the infrared spectroscopy community. The instrument sends out signals to a proprietary card in the computer for data processing, mainly FFT, I suppose. It looks like this, with a large Xilinx FPGA chip, a Zilog processor, some memory chips and a PLX PCI controller. I could not identify U1 and U2 sfter a quick search. They are probably quite important for communication. [image: Proprietary PCI card]

On the instrument side, there is a 20-pin connector that sends signal to the card. [image: 0-pin connector on the instrument]

My question is, based on these information, would it be possible to decode the signal passed between the card and the instrument? An FT-IR signal is basically an array of intensity vs. mirror position. Doing an FFT on the array one backs out intensity vs. wavelength. So the computer needs to send signal for driving the mirror and getting back digitized signal from the instrument.

A plan B would be to chop most of the existing electronics and tap out the analog signal directly from the detector while find a way to drive the mirror by oneself.

Answer (score 1):

U1 and U2 are RS422 transmitter and receiver chips, so that is possibly the electrical interface.

Comment: I am looking for the spec sheets for U1 and U2, what names should I use for the search?

Comment: It reads on the chips. AM26LS31 and AM26LS32. Other manufactured by Philips ans other by Texas Instruments.